# Provisioning target computer fails with VS 2013

Tags: windows, kernel, visual-studio-debugging

WDK: 8.1
VS: 2013 Pro
Host OS: Win 7 x64
Target OS: Win 10 Enterprise N x64

Provisioning fails at installing WDTF (Windows Driver Test Framework):
[image]

Log shows:

```
Initialize: Computer: 
Progress event: Current: 11, Max: 17, Message: "Installing driver test framework"
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Computer Name: DESKTOP-OFDQ6IA
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Architecture: AMD64
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Operating System Version: 6.3.9600.0
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Operating System Product Type: 1
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Domain Joined: False
Initialize: Computer: DESKTOP-OFDQ6IA
InternalRunTest: Host Computer: ROBI-WIN7
InternalRunTest: Host Architecture: x86
InternalRunTest: Host 64bit Operating System: True
InternalRunTest: Host Operating System Version: 6.1.7601.65536
InternalRunTest: Process Administrator Privilege: True
Initialize: Computer: DESKTOP-OFDQ6IA
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Computer Name: DESKTOP-OFDQ6IA
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Architecture: AMD64
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Operating System Version: 6.3.9600.0
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Operating System Product Type: 1
GetMachinePropertiesFromService: Domain Joined: False
ExecuteProcess: Arguments: "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\msiexec.exe" /select:"@Name='Installing driver test framework'" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Installing_driver_test_framework_00009.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[14:04:20:990]: [Installing driver test framework] Command Line:
te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\msiexec.exe" /select:"@Name='Installing driver test framework'" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Installing_driver_test_framework_00009.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
Initialize: Computer: 
Initialize: Computer: 
Created new result:
  Path: C:\Users\robi\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DriverTest\TestRepository\Results\Installing driver test framework 00009.xml
  Log Path: C:\Users\robi\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DriverTest\TestRepository\Results\Installing driver test framework 00009.log
  Computer: DESKTOP-OFDQ6IA
  Test Binary: msiexec.exe
  Test Name:  Installing driver test framework
  Test Display Name: Installing driver test framework
Initialize: Computer: 
RemoteExecute: Binary: msiexec.exe
RemoteExecution: Arguments: /i "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Setup\Windows Driver Testing Framework (WDTF) Runtime Libraries-x64_en-us.msi" /qb- KITTARGET=1 /l*v "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Logs\Windows Driver Testing Framework (WDTF) Runtime Libraries-x64_en-us.msi_install.log"
Initialize: Computer: 
RemoteExecute: Process creation return code: 0
RemoteExecute: Process exit code: 1603
Result completed
Test process exit code: 1603
Result status updated: Fail
```

Installing manually results in same error. Windows Feature Pack for Win 10 N has been installed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it by running:
WDK 8.1 + VS2013 Pro + Target OS Win 8.1 Pro

Then provisioning went ahead without problems...

Comment: so it was because of mismatch between SDK version and operating system etc.